# KeyError: u'NearestNeighbors' on loading saved model from tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to do the following:

- Run kmeans clustering using tensorflow (1.8.0)
- Save the model using `kmeans.export_savedmodel`
- Use the model using `tf.saved_model.loader.load`

I am using the exact script at: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering

I am using following code for saving the model:

Input Reciever:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = {"x": tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2])}
    model_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,shape=[None],name='input')
    receiver_tensors = {"model_inputs": model_placeholder}
    features = tf.parse_example(model_placeholder, feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

Export:

```
kmeans.export_savedmodel("/path/", serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

To import I use:

```
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],"/path")
```

On last step I run into this issue:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restore_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "/Users/z001t3k/work/codebase/ContentPipeline/cep-scripts/cep/datacollection/algorithms/cluster_model/1525963476")
  File "/Users/z001t3k/python_virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 219, in load
    saver = tf_saver.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def_to_load, **saver_kwargs)
  File "/Users/z001t3k/python_virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1955, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/z001t3k/python_virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 743, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/Users/z001t3k/python_virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/z001t3k/python_virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 460, in import_graph_def
    _RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
  File "/Users/z001t3k/python_virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 227, in _RemoveDefaultAttrs
    op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: u'NearestNeighbors'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow is having trouble locating the `NearestNeighbors` op, which is part of the graph you're loading. Ops defined in contrib are loaded dynamically when you import the corresponding contrib package in Python.

So just add

```
import tensorflow.contrib.factorization
```

before loading the SavedModel.